# .NET connecting to AXIS Service. Methods don't have params or Datatypes

Tags: c#, .net, interop, wsdl, axis

I got a few problems using the AXIS Service Reference from my .NET Project. I simply added the reference today int VS2010, but the provided Method do all have no return Type or Params. I just looked at the generated WSDL which looks like this : ( Shorted this Schema, maybe there are missing some message elements, but lets focus on the parameter thing )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:intf="urn:api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcSession" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns2="http://lang.java" xmlns:impl="urn:api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcSession" targetNamespace="urn:api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcSession" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcSession">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://lang.java" />
      <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      <xsd:complexType name="WebserviceException">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="cause" nillable="true" type="xsd:anyType" />
          <xsd:element name="message" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="loginRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="in0" type="xsd:long" />
    <wsdl:part name="in1" type="xsd:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="in2" type="xsd:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="SessionWebservice">
    <wsdl:operation name="login" parameterOrder="in0 in1 in2">
      <wsdl:input name="loginRequest" message="impl:loginRequest" />
      <wsdl:output name="loginResponse" message="impl:loginResponse" />
      <wsdl:fault name="WebserviceException" message="impl:WebserviceException" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="RpcSessionSoapBinding" type="impl:SessionWebservice">
    <wsdlsoap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc" />
     <wsdl:operation name="login">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
      <wsdl:input name="loginRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcSession" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="loginResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcSession" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="WebserviceException">
        <wsdlsoap:fault use="encoded" name="WebserviceException" namespace="urn:api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcSession" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="SessionWebserviceService">
    <wsdl:port name="RpcSession" binding="impl:RpcSessionSoapBinding">
      <wsdlsoap:address location="https://api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcSession" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Afterwards I looked at my generated proxy class "reference.cs", notifying that there are no params in the methods.

```
namespace OptivoInterfaceApp.broadmailSession {


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="urn:api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcSession", ConfigurationName="broadmailSession.SessionWebservice")]
    public interface SessionWebservice {


        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute()]
        void login();

    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public interface SessionWebserviceChannel : OptivoInterfaceApp.broadmailSession.SessionWebservice, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public partial class SessionWebserviceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<OptivoInterfaceApp.broadmailSession.SessionWebservice>, OptivoInterfaceApp.broadmailSession.SessionWebservice {

        public SessionWebserviceClient() {
        }

        public SessionWebserviceClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName) {
        }

        public SessionWebserviceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public SessionWebserviceClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public SessionWebserviceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public void login() {
            base.Channel.login();
        }
    }
}
```

Do I have to add the params manually to my proxy class or am I doin something else wrong ? I just tried to add the params manually but on the methodcall I only get an exception.

Any Hints for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use WRAPPED style.

More info: http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#ServiceStylesRPCDocumentWrappedAndMessage